# vertically centralizing the object with CSS

Tags: html, css

My HTML front-end side part is expressed like this:

```
<div class="input_wrap">
    <input type="text" title="money" class="input_text price" name="amount"
     onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'');
     this.value=make_price_format(this.value);" 
     onblur="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'');
     this.value=make_price_format(this.value);">
     <span class="unit">Euro</span>
</div>
```

As you see, there is a textbox and next to it, there is a `span.unit` "Euro".

And corresponding CSS is like below.

```
#register_apply .apply_table .input_wrap span.unit
{
   vertical-align:middle;
   text-align:center;
   padding-top:30px;
   margin-top:30px;
   font-size:22px;
   color:#646464;
}
```

`#register_apply` and `apply_table` is upper class names. As you see, I added some attributes to make Euro placed vertically middle. Since the text box height is `60px`, I want to place "Euro" approximately `30px` position from the top. But I was not able to control the place with `margin` and `padding`.

What can I do next?

Comment: @akash unless you give them `display: inline-block;` that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add padding to an element it must either be inline-block or block.  As you are wanting your unit to be on the same line as your input, I would go with inline-block:

```css
.input_text {
  height: 60px;
}
.unit {
  display:inline-block;
  padding-top:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input_wrap">
  <input type="text" title="money" class="input_text price" name="amount" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'');
     this.value=make_price_format(this.value);" onblur="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'');
     this.value=make_price_format(this.value);">
  <span class="unit">Euro</span>
</div>
```

If you are just wanting vertical alignment, then you should just be able to add [`vertical-align:middle` to the textbox and that should work](http://jsfiddle.net/uLvdpv3t/)

Answer (score 1):

```
.input_wrap{
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0
}
```

This centers a element in all directions. All you have to do give your parent `position: relative;` Play around with the top, left etc. values to allign it where you want